# Why does the trigger execution log for a sendEmail function of my google script project says it's completed, and yet no actual emails are being sent?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, triggers

I am trying to create a function in google script that attempts to automatically send emails to a user once they entered an email into the sheet. I have set up a trigger for this and according to the execution log, the attempts that I made were all successful, however, no emails are actually being sent to the test emails that i entered. Below is my code:

```
function sendEmail(e) {
var esheete = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if (!e || !e.range) {
    console.error("Event object or range is missing.");
    return;
  }

  const dissheete = e.range.getSheet();


  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    
    const rowr = e.range.getRow();
    const emailAddress = dissheete.getRange(rowr, 7).getValue();
    const nonEmptyValues = getLastNonEmptyCellValues(dissheete, [2, 3, 4]);
        const teacherName = nonEmptyValues[0];
        const meetingDetails = nonEmptyValues[1];
        const meetTime = nonEmptyValues[2];
    const queueSlots = sheete.getRange(rowr, 5).getValue();
    const queueEntryName = e.value;
    const subject = "Academic Advising Schedule: Slot Confirmation";
    const message = "Greetings, " + queueEntryName + "!\n\n" +
                    "You have been added to the meeting queue. Please take note of the meeting's details. \n\n" +
                    "Meeting with: Mr/Ma'am " + teacherName + "\n" +
                    "Meeting Details: " + meetingDetails + "\n" +
                    "Meeting Time: " + meetTime + "\n" +
                    "Queue Slot: " + queueSlots + "\n\n" +
                    "Please keep a copy of this message, and take note of the time when you received this. In case someone replaces your name in the Queueing Sheet, please present this confirmation email to your adviser." +
                    "Please make sure to attend the said schedule. Thank you!";
    
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}

function getLastNonEmptyCellValues(dissheete, columns) {
  var lastRow = dissheete.getLastRow();
  var nonEmptyValues = [];

  // Iterate over each column in the array
  columns.forEach(function(column) {
    for (var i = lastRow; i > 0; i--) {
      var cellValue = dissheete.getRange(i, column).getValue();
      if (cellValue !== "") {
        nonEmptyValues.push(cellValue); // Store non-empty value
        break; // Move to the next column
      }
    }
  });

  return nonEmptyValues;
}
```

I already tried deleting and restarting the trigger, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, if your showing script is your whole script, I think that `sheete` of `const queueSlots = sheete.getRange(rowr, 5).getValue();` is not declared. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.

In your situation, `sheete` is `dissheete`? I think that `esheete` is the same with `dissheete`. If my understanding is correct, please modify it as follows and test it again.

#### From:

```
const queueSlots = sheete.getRange(rowr, 5).getValue();
```

#### To:

```
const queueSlots = dissheete.getRange(rowr, 5).getValue();
```

### Added:

From the following reply,

> I tried to do what you just have said, I deleted the other functions and kept only the sendEmail function, the trigger was completed but no email has been sent still.

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, in your specification, it seems that it is required to set the email address to column "G". From your reply, I'm worried that this might not be done. And also, I'm worried about other errors. So, I proposed the following modified script.

Please test the following script. In this case, after `sendEmail` was installed as a OnEdit trigger, when you edit the column "F" and an error occurs, the error message is shown in a dialog. You can see the error message at the dialog. If an error like `Failed to send email: no recipient at sendEmail` occurs, please set the email address to column "G" and edit column "F" again. When an email is sent, a toast is shown.

In this case, `getLastNonEmptyCellValues` is not modified.

```js
function sendEmail(e) {
  try {

    // var esheete = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // This is not used.
    if (!e || !e.range) {
      console.error("Event object or range is missing.");
      return;
    }
    const dissheete = e.range.getSheet();
    if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
      const rowr = e.range.getRow();
      const emailAddress = dissheete.getRange(rowr, 7).getValue();
      const nonEmptyValues = getLastNonEmptyCellValues(dissheete, [2, 3, 4]);
      const teacherName = nonEmptyValues[0];
      const meetingDetails = nonEmptyValues[1];
      const meetTime = nonEmptyValues[2];
      const queueSlots = dissheete.getRange(rowr, 5).getValue(); // Modified
      const queueEntryName = e.value;
      const subject = "Academic Advising Schedule: Slot Confirmation";
      const message = "Greetings, " + queueEntryName + "!\n\n" +
        "You have been added to the meeting queue. Please take note of the meeting's details. \n\n" +
        "Meeting with: Mr/Ma'am " + teacherName + "\n" +
        "Meeting Details: " + meetingDetails + "\n" +
        "Meeting Time: " + meetTime + "\n" +
        "Queue Slot: " + queueSlots + "\n\n" +
        "Please keep a copy of this message, and take note of the time when you received this. In case someone replaces your name in the Queueing Sheet, please present this confirmation email to your adviser." +
        "Please make sure to attend the said schedule. Thank you!";
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      e.source.toast("Done");
    }
  } catch ({ stack }) {
    Browser.msgBox(stack);
  }
}

function getLastNonEmptyCellValues(dissheete, columns) {
  var lastRow = dissheete.getLastRow();
  var nonEmptyValues = [];

  // Iterate over each column in the array
  columns.forEach(function(column) {
    for (var i = lastRow; i > 0; i--) {
      var cellValue = dissheete.getRange(i, column).getValue();
      if (cellValue !== "") {
        nonEmptyValues.push(cellValue); // Store non-empty value
        break; // Move to the next column
      }
    }
  });

  return nonEmptyValues;
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, I missed that, thank you. I applied what you said but there has been no improvement.

Comment: @meue1004 Thank you for replying. About `oh yeah, I missed that, thank you. I applied what you said but there has been no improvement.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, in order to correctly replicate `no improvement`, it is required to know your situation. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the modified script? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Here's a duplicate of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E9Zropa3HYpgQORG4dmC3AQUxaeKvtc9xQO5sgfL2UE/edit?usp=sharing 

I am not sure  if this is what you meant, or should I post the whole script above and attach the picture of my spreadsheet?

Thank you.

Comment: @meue1004 Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I tested my proposed modification using your sample Spreadsheetwhen `sendEmail` is installed as the installable trigger of OnEdit and when a valid email address is used and column "F" is edited, no error occurred and an email is sent. So, I cannot replicate `no improvement`. I apologize for this.

Comment: @meue1004 But, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I found other functions including `onEdit` in your script. I'm worried that those might be the reason for your current issue. So, I would like to recommend testing my proposed modified script after removing all existing scripts. Because your other script is not related to this question. I understand that your question is to resolve the issue of the function `sendEmail` showing in your question.

Comment: It worked for you? I tried to do what you just have said, I deleted the other functions and kept only the sendEmail function, the trigger was completed but no email has been sent still. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: @meue1004 Thank you for replying. From your reply, now, I updated the script of your provided sample Spreadsheet. Please confirm it. If you use this modified script, please install OnEdit trigger to sendEmail. And, please set a valid email address to column "G" of your Spreadsheet. And, please edit a cell of column "F". By this, the modified script worked using the email address. If the valie email address is not put, the email is not sent even when this modified script is used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: late reply, sorry. I just saw this today, tried it immediately, and it worked! Thanks a lot.